Entity Framework is removing all rows before add new one
I've got a three main classes in my code:
public class AppRole : ITenantEntity<Guid>
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> AppUserRoles { get; } = new HashSet<AppUserRole>();
}

public class AppUser
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class AppUserRole
{
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }
}

and mapping for those:
builder
    .Entity<AppRole>()
    .HasMany(s => s.AppUserRoles)
    .WithOne(s => s.Role)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.RoleId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder
    .Entity<AppUser>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.TenantId });

builder
    .Entity<AppUserRole>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });

Use case in my app looks like that:

In app are a lot of roles -> AppRole
In app are a lot of users -> AppUser
User can be attached to n-approles

So into db I have got data like that:
AppRole - Id: 1, Name: "test", ...
AppRole - Id: 2, Name: "test2", ...
AppUser - UserId: "myuser", ...
AppUserRole - UserId: "myuser", RoleId: 1
AppUserRole - UserId: "myuser", RoleId: 2
When I'm trying to add the new AppRole to table then Entity Framework into first step is deleting every row in AppRoles table, executing query:
DELETE FROM [AppRoles]
WHERE [Id] = @p0 AND [TenantId] = @p1;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

and on the next step is executing insert:
INSERT INTO [AppRoles] ([Id], [TenantId], [Name])
VALUES (@p22, @p23, @p24),
(@p25, @p26, @p27),
...
(@p55, @p56, @p57);

This mechanism affect that all rows from AppUserRole table are deleting.
That's the real problem.
Disappearing rows from AppUserRole table
To better understanding problem let's see the other example:
Imagine that there are 20 students in the class. Each has their grades from various subjects. During the year, one student joins. Should this result in clearing all the data on the grades of the remaining students?
I don't think so.
That is the problem. Data from AppUserRoles shouldn't be deleted when new item is adding to AppRole.
Does anybody see any bug here?
Why ef is doing delete before add?
I have to ask here about that because my tries of fix that by myself doesn't fix the problem.
I forgot - that's the code which is executing the update:
public virtual async Task<T> Update(T item)
{
    var originalItem = await this.DbSet.SingleAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
    this.Mapper.Map(item, originalItem);
    await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return this.Mapper.Map<T>(originalItem);
}


"When I'm trying to modify the AppRole table by add/modify/delete some rows" honestly it sounds like you are telling ef to delete some rows... Also we don't see what Mapper.Map() does - I think that's important for debugging.

I'm just trying to add new approle to table. Mapper.Map() doesn't do anything special. It's executing for every object in application but only adding new approle seems to be broken. If the bug will be here then every operation in app will make a troubles. I think that the problem is somewhere in mapping but cannot to find it

I read your comment once again and discovered that a few missing information were missing in my question. I added them makes full context more understable.

As far as your entity modeling goes, it does make sense that if you have a cascade delete on role <-> appuserrole then deleting an appuserrole will delete the role. I personally would look at the database to verify this, but you may want to just remove that particular cascading delete.

Probably you don't get the idea. Adding a new AppRole item is flushing a AppUserRole data. It shouldn't work like that. Especially when is adding a new item without any existing relation in AppUserRole.

Imagine that there are 20 students in the class. Each has their grades from various subjects. During the year, one student joins. Should this result in clearing all the data on the grades of the remaining students? I don't think so. That is the problem. Data from AppUserRoles shouldn't be deleted when new item is adding to AppRole

You will have to show your code. It is not clear why EF Core would create a delete statement. We only see .SaveChanges() we don't see what you are doing with your data. In any case, I don't see anything obvious in your "model builder" that would explain the behavior - unless it is the cascading delete (but you claim you are not deleting anything so its very unclear).

For correct mapping collection navigation properties, you should use package Automapper.Collection

When working with collections you need to be careful that your code or mappers do not end up replacing the collection instance. This line also likely will cause a problem when reading data:
public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> AppUserRoles { get; } = new HashSet<AppUserRole>();

Update this to:
public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> AppUserRoles { get; protected set;} = new HashSet<AppUserRole>();

Then when updating your parent where you want to make changes to the child collection, eager load it with Include():
var originalItem = await this.DbSet
    .Include(x => x.AppUserRoles)
    .SingleAsync(...)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

this.Mapper.Map(item, originalItem);

If you are looking to then add an AppUserRole, you may want to have the mapper ignore any collections or references and handle those manually. You don't want the mapper trying to overwrite collections with new collections (protected setter should help avoid that) but also for singular references you often don't want existing entity values being changed, but instead, loading the new entity(ies) to reference and replacing the references in the parent.
